# как установить python django

Tags: python, django

я пытался установить python django но у меня выдовало так в cmd

```
c:\Scripts>pip install django
```

> Requirement already satisfied: django in c:\users\1\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (3.0.1)
>   Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\1\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from django) (2019.3)
>   Requirement already satisfied: asgiref~=3.2 in c:\users\1\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from django) (3.2.3)
>   Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in c:\users\1\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from django) (0.3.0)

все остальные библиотеки скачиваються

Comment: Это означает, что всё давным-давно успешно установлено

Comment: Это так же означает, что возможно имеются конфликты окружения если у вас не работает сам Django, и возможно он установлен не там где ожидается.

Answer (score 1):

Данная ошибка означает, что у Вас уже установлены данные пакеты. 
Если Вы понимаете, что данные модули всё равно не работают, то ошибка может быть в том, что в файле модуля стоит один путь к интерпретатору, а pip устанавливает пакеты по другому пути. 
Второй вариант, что у Вас стоят 2 версии python. 
Проверьте путь до Вашего python и путь установленный в pip, а так же установленные версии python.